# Children's book about a kid traveling out of his body during sleep in New York city

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, dreams

Children's book about a kid traveling out of his body during sleep in New York city while visiting his grandfather. Then meets Babe Ruth, etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. This is very terse at the moment. Could you please [edit] in some extra details? Perhaps you could expand on the "etc"?

Comment: When did you read this?  Where?  What language was it in?  Were there illustrations?  Can you describe any of them?  How long is he out of body?  How does he get back?

Comment: This might be completely out of left field, but was there a character named "Alex" in it, and perhaps another who could prop themselves up in the air to sleep, with a scene where someone accidentally messes with the colors of sunrise?